# Thread pool join function

Tags: c, multithreading, threadpool

I am trying to create a thread pool in C. In that, I have to implement a join function which takes each thread as an argument; in essence, it's similar to the `thread_join` function. Can anyone provide me with resources regarding how to implement simple thread join function?

```
//structure that contains a pthread 
struct ThreadID; 

// from this run method I am creating threads in a thread pool
int ThreadPool_run(struct ThreadPool *, struct ThreadID *, void *(*run)(void *), void *);

// this is the join function   
int ThreadPool_join(struct ThreadID, void **);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Note that you would need to be a lot more specific about the platform you're working on and the thread library you are planning to use underneath this.  There are major differences between threads on Unix (POSIX pthreads) and Windows, and the C11 standard nominally has thread support, but it isn't always implemented. Also, _questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Comment: Joining on a thread pool barely make any sense. You  might want to check how java's `ExecutorService` and C# `ThreadPool` work. They return future or task object on which you can join. You never join on a thread in a thread pool, as it might never stop running (busy running other tasks).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you completely understand the concept of a thread pool. You should not have the notion of thread going in nor out of the thread pool interface. In fact, I prefer the java's `ExecutorService` name. It better encapsulates the concept. Basically, you want to run tasks asynchronously, without bothering with thread lifetime.

Such a service would have an interface that looks like this:

```
typedef struct executor executor_t;
typedef struct executor_options executor_options_t;
typedef struct executor_task executor_task_t;
typedef struct blocking_queue blocking_queue_t;
typedef struct future future_t;
typedef void *(*task_t)(void* data);

int executor_init(const executor_options_t options);
int executor_submit(const executor_t *const executor, future_t *const future, const task_t task, const void *const data);
int executor_destroy(const executor_t *const executor);

int blocking_queue_init(blocking_queue_t *const queue);
int blocking_queue_enqueue(const blocking_queue_t *const queue, const void *const data);
int blocking_queue_dequeue(const blocking_queue_t *const queue, const void ** data);
int blocking_queue_destroy(const blocking_queue_t *const queue);

int future_init(future_t *const future);
int future_wait(const future_t *const future);
int future_destroy(const future_t *const future);
```

Structures might look like this:

```
struct executor_options {
    int min_thread;
    int max_thread;
    int max_idle_ms;
};

struct executor {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_t *threads;
    executor_options_t options;
    blocking_queue_t *queue;
};

struct executor_task {
    task_t task;
    void *data;
    future_t *future;
};

struct blocking_queue {
    executor_task_t *tasks;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t empty;
    pthread_cond_t full;
    bool_t is_empty;
    bool_t is_full;
};

struct future {
    void *result;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t computed;
    bool_t is_computed;
};
```

In `executor_init`, you would initialize all threads. Those threads should block on a queue awaiting tasks, running them, and notifying the future's condition to unblock awaiters.  In `executor_submit`, the given future should be initialized and the task, along with the future, should be queued to be computed by workers asynchronously. The future should then be useable by a user to await the result of the task. Finally, `executor_destroy` should wait for all remaining tasks to be computed, preventing any new tasks from being submitted. It finally releases all resources and return.